# wxPython - How to get MenuItem from event?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

Using wxPython, I have a frame setup with a menu and a status bar. The menu is generated from an indented text file, from which I use to create a nice nested menu bar with each menu item bound to a specific function. I have a "Toggle Status Bar" menu check item which is bound OnToggleStatusBar().

I would like to see if the menu item is checked or not and react accordingly, but I cannot seem to access the menuItem from the event. If I use GetId(), how can that be used to find the menu item? I tried event.GetId() with FindWindowById() but got nothing. I also tried event.GetEventObject(), which returned a menu but not a menu item.

```
def OnToggleStatusBar(self, event):
    id = event.GetId()
    menu = event.GetEventObject()
    menuItem = menu.FindWindowById(id) #does not work
    print self.FindByWindowId(id) # prints None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to find the item, you can use `wxMenuBar::IsChecked()`, which will do it for you, directly. And you can either just store the menu bar in `self.menuBar` or retrieve it from the frame using its `GetMenuBar()` method.

Comment: Will this work if I have multiple items that are checkable? I would think you'd need a way to differentiate between items in that case

Comment: Even if there are multiple items, all of them must have unique IDs, so why would there be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit convoluted, but not too bad. Basically you need to use the menu's `FindItem` method, which takes the string name of the menu item. This returns its id, which you can then use the menu's `FindItemById` method for. Here's a quick and dirty example:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="wx.Menu Tutorial")

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        # Create menu bar
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()

        # create check menu
        checkMenu = wx.Menu()
        wgItem = checkMenu.Append(wx.NewId(), "Wells Fargo", "", wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onFargo, wgItem)
        citiItem = checkMenu.Append(wx.NewId(), "Citibank", "", wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        geItem = checkMenu.Append(wx.NewId(), "GE Money Bank", "", wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        menuBar.Append(checkMenu, "&Check")

        # Attach menu bar to frame
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onFargo(self, event):
        """"""
        menu = event.GetEventObject()
        item_id = menu.FindItem("Wells Fargo")
        item = menu.FindItemById(item_id)
        print item.IsChecked()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the event to access the data you want.

```
print event.Id
print event.Selection # returns 1 if checked 0 if not checked 
print event.IsChecked() # returns True if checked False if not checked
```

print out all of the attributes with:

```
print dir(event)
```